# Flattern sub dirs & prepend file name with dir name using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line-interface

This works:

```
ls -SF data/*/*/* | xargs -I % cp % migrations/db.tmp/
```

But I wish to prepend the filename with the directory name"
e.g.

```
data/folder1/subfolder1/file1.js -> data/folder1-subfolder1-file1.js
```

The next step I tried is:(but could not get it to work)

```
 ls -SF migrations/db/*/*/* | xargs -I % cp % migrations/db.tmp/$(basename %)-%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ls`, especially with the `-F` option:

```
cd data
for f in */*/*; do cp "$f" "${f//\//-}"; done
```

Here's a much trickier method

```
cd data
printf "%s\n" */*/* | sed 'h; s,/,-,g; x; G; s/\n/ /; s/^/cp /'
```

That will output a bunch of `cp` commands. Pipe into `| sh` to execute them.